# How can I use CRUD at UI of ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, crud, scaffold

I use **MvcControllerWithContextScaffolde** to create Scaffold,
it is my **Index.cshtml**

```
<td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PoNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qty)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NetPrice)
        </td>
```

and website can show the data,but Delete、Details、Edit .cshtml didn't work.
I have fix the code ,but it still didn't work.
and it is my **Delete.cshtml**

```
<div>
<h4>PoItem</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="row">
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PoNo)
    </dt>
    <dt class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PoNo)
    </dt>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemNo)
    </dt>
    <dt class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemNo)
    </dt>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductNo)
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductNo)
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Qty)
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Qty)
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NetPrice)
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NetPrice)
    </dd>
</dl>

<form asp-action="Delete">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="PoNo" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ItemNo" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" /> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</form>
```

it is my Table of Database.I use primary key with  two Columns.

```
CREATE TABLE po_items (
po_no INTEGER,
item_no INTEGER,
product_no INTEGER,
qty INTEGER,
net_price NUMERIC,
PRIMARY KEY (po_no, item_no)
```

I think the problem is about I have two primary key,but i don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: You could have a look on this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0) still if you encountered the problem feel free to share. You can use [Update like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: To  Md Farid Uddin Kiron :    I have  see the website ,but I think we have a little different.The website didn't use  Composite Key.

Comment: Well, may I know what's your purpose about is composite key on client side? Are you using database first approach?

Comment: To Md Farid Uddin Kiron : Yes I use Database First  ,and it use composite key. I find when I use Primary key it can go will on CRUD, but when I use the database of composite key,it will be erreo on CRUD.

Comment: You are providing `item_no` as well right? so I am not sure why you cannot `CRUD` it, if both the primary key given so it shouldn't encounter problem

Comment: To Md Farid Uddin Kiron : 「providing item_no」 it means I input the item_no from myself?

Comment: Yes from your user input, even if you need to get it from backedn then you can do it as well. But need to submit it while you send data to database, because it is also a primary key (composite) so need to provide it together

Comment: To Md Farid Uddin Kiron : Yes ,I providing item_no. and database can succesful recive.

Answer (score 0):

you can use two foriegn key not primary
so tou should have one primary key in one table and many foriegn key if you want in ordet to relate with another relation

Comment: This should be as comment not an answer

Comment: TO Ossama Abd: I think Composite Key is allow to use, Can you tell me the reason?Why